# Getting HTML with file_get_contents() and ajax: chars are not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I retrieve html data from a website with my proxy.php and main.js. Here come the relevant excerpts:

**proxy.php:**

```
<?php

$url = addslashes($_GET['url']);
$output = file_get_contents($url);
echo $output;
```

**ajax.js:**

```
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'proxy.php?url=http://www.example.com',
        cache   : false,
        dataType: 'html'
    })
    .done(function (html) {
        // do something
    });
```

My problem is that special chars like "ä", "ö", "ü" etc. in German are not displayed correctly. For example, instead of "Nächte" I get the ouput "NÃ¤chte". Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Comment: You need to set your page's `charcode` to the same as the site you're downloading from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying a header in the proxy.php file might help to ensure an appropriate character encoding is used. e.g.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $url = addslashes($_GET['url']);
    $output = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $output;
?>
```